# Django + Ajax . Can't find variable:ajaxPost

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, django

I downloaded a bit old project from repo(didn't updated it for few months) and it appeared ajax doesn't work somehow. In `pip freeze` I checked library I used `djangoajax==2.4`

In templates js code it looks like this:

```
ajaxPost('/authfb/', {'username': fb_name , 'fb_id': fb_id, 'csrfmiddlewaretoken': getCookie('csrftoken')}, function(){ });
```

And issue in browser logs is that `Can't find variable:ajaxPost`

I just don't know what that library was and maybe it's outdated? How to check?

Or can be problem connected with something else? I am sure it worked before. All ajax, js, jQuery links and etc is correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To perform ajax client side use JQuery:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/authfb/",
    data: {'username': fb_name , 'fb_id': fb_id, 'csrfmiddlewaretoken': getCookie('csrftoken')},
    success: function(){}
});
```